# How can I get old data on input form values Angular

Tags: angular

I am updating data with this form in Angular. I would like to get the old input's values when I click on reset button. Can you guys help me please.

```
<form #myform="ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit(myform)" class="form form-register">
  <mat-form-field fxLayout="row" appearance="outline" >
  <label for="name">Name: </label>
   <input name="name" id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="list['name']" required>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field fxLayout="row" appearance="outline" >
  <label for="Location">Location: </label>
  <input name="location" id="location" type="text"  [(ngModel)]="list['location']" required>
  </mat-form-field>
  <input type="hidden" #charactername="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="list['id']" name="id">


 <div>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" (click)="clearForm(myform)"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Register">
 </div>
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the same time that "list" is created, copy its values to another variable. Then in clearForm(), copy the values back into "list". You can even remove the parameter "myForm", as the values it contains won't be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can deep clone the myForm value before resetting the form. You can try something like this

```
clearForm(myform) {
   const copy = cloneDeep(myForm);
   reset();
}
```

Npm package that you can use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone-deep